# Release local variable automatically

Tags: c, linux

I call a sub-function twice, but second time can print local variable with the value form previous call. I tested this on Linux. Why second string point to same address with previous one? How to avoid that?
Thanks a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  second();
  second();
  return 0;
}
int second (){
  char tmp[40];
  printf("%s \n", tmp);
  strcpy (tmp, "set");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It just *happens* to point to the same data because nothing else in the system overwrote it yet. Why do you need it to be reset? You should set it to what you want before using it.

Comment: I my case, I use sscanf() to assign value to a string, but sscanf("\n","%s" tmp) will do nothing since string only has a newline character. Then tmp remains the same value form previous call. "\n" comes from a fgets() which read a empty line form a file.

Comment: I think I just initialize tmp before sscanf() since it may fail.

Comment: One way to fix the 'problem' is to create a function `void third(int n){ char buffer[40]; snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.39d", n); printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer); }` and call `third(391);` between the two calls to `second()`. The function `third()` reuses the same space that `second()` (ab)uses, so the value set by the first call to `second()` is overwritten before the second call to it. It never was reliably available; now it is reliably unavailable. However, using uninitialized variables like `tmp` in `second()` is always undefined behaviour; anything can happen and it is legitimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int second (){
  char tmp[40];
  printf("%s \n", tmp);  // undefined behavior here
  strcpy (tmp, "set");
  return 0;
}
```

Since this is undefined behavior (reading uninitialized memory) you may (or may not) get the results from the first call.

Answer (score 1):

The second instance of `tmp` can have the same address as the first one because their lifetimes do not overlap.  By the time you are accessing the second instance of `tmp`, the first instance does not exist anymore.

As noted by others, the real problem here is that you are accessing an uninitialised variable, which has undefined behaviour.  In this case, the manifestation of that undefined behaviour is apparently *"you see the contents of an older variable that no longer exists"*.  You can fix this by initialising `tmp`:

```
int second ()
{
  char tmp[40] = "";
  printf("%s \n", tmp);
  strcpy (tmp, "set");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `printf(">%s<\n", tmp)` or the like, else no printable text will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you just repeated to `declare tmp[40]` again, clearing its data inside so why dont you try your `char tmp[40] as a global variable`? are you trying to append the word SET every call of the function?